# How to bring exchange rate sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (Table1) with payments stored in different currencies and another table (Table2) that contains currency conversion rates, as presented below.

**Table1**

[image]

**Table2**

[image]

I wanna export a query which generates the data as follows:

[image]
No matter what currency has the payment the result should be presented in LEI and EUR per row based on the rate of exchange on the day of payment.

Eg.

```
ID   Value  Date of payment   Currency
XX1   100    10.07.2020         EUR

   Date      Currency  Ex_Rate
10.07.2020     EUR      4.5537
```

The export should be:

```
ID   Date of payment    Value[LEI]   Value[EUR]
XX1    10.07.2020        455.37        100
```

Comment: Can you please share the queries you have written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 t1.ID
 ,t1.date_of_payment
 ,CASE WHEN t1.currency='LEI' THEN payment ELSE payment*t2.exchange_rate END as Value[LEI]
 ,CASE WHEN t1.currency='EUR' 
        THEN payment 
      ELSE CASE WHEN t1.currency='LEI' THEN payment/t3.exchange_rate 
           ELSE payment*t2.exchange_rate/t3.exchange_rate 
           END 
    END as Value[EUR]
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.AtDate=t1.date_of_payment and t2.code=t1.currency
LEFT JOIN Table2 t3 ON t3.AtDate=t1.date_of_payment and t3.code='EUR'
```

From my knowledge, exchange rates are frozen during the weekend. So you will probably have to adjust the query if you receive payments during the weekend and you don't have entries in your echange rate table for weekends.

Comment: Thanks Gabi. Can you please export values with "," as decimal not "."?

Comment: I was trying with replace(cast(t1."PAYVal"/t3."EXCValue" as decimal(12,2)), '.', ',') but I have an error

Comment: I think it should work, you just need to cast it as varchar(32) instead of decimal(12,2) as replace works on strings.

Comment: I posted a new question in which I loaded the provided code. I want to add something else. can you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915010/select-min-date-from-another-table-in-sql/62915059#62915059