# select MIN (Date) from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given 2 tables of data I wanna extract min date from the second one in a third table using a query as follow:

**Table 1**

```
   id   value  date_of_payment  risk
    x1    100     01.01.2020     15X
    x1    50      01.05.2020     15Y
```

**Table 2**

```
id  start        end         risk
x1  01.01.2019   01.12.2021   15X
x1  01.05.2019   01.04.2022   15Y
```

**Table 3** (result)

```
id   start(min)       end(max)          value   date_of_payment  risk
x1   01.01.2019       01.04.2022        100      01.01.2020      15X
x1   01.01.2019       01.04.2022        50       01.05.2020      15Y
```

I do not need to filter date by risk.

Please find below my code:

```
select p."Index", p."PAYVal", p."PAYDate"
from "DAMPay" as p
left join "PolsRisc" as pr on p."PRID" = pr."Index"
where p."PAYDate" between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-30'
```

I wanna add on the selection min(pr."AsigStart")

Thanks

Comment: If you have "2 tables", why does your query have a dozen table references.

Comment: because i need to return info that is stored in different tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your feedback. I'm noob on sql. Can u be more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has nothing to do with the question.  But based on the question, I would recommend a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select min(t2.start) as start, min(t2.end) as end
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = t1.id
     ) t2
     on true;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fee5ea945ebcdfa33bc0f4db9b91b90b) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the code works.

Comment: thanks Gordon. I was trying to use the code provided but I have an error. I adjusted the code and the question for a better understanding

Comment: @Alin-IustinianToderita . . . Are you suggesting this doesn't work?  The logic looks correct to me.

Comment: no.I was not able to apply it to my code. please see my code above. thanks

Comment: @Alin-IustinianToderita . . . The code works.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I was checking the formula and it works well. However I'm not able to put some additional conditions inside. Can you help me with? I wanna add the condition that the start to be between '2020-06-01' and '2020-06-30' and also to show only min(t2.startt)

Comment: @Alin-IustinianToderita . . . You should ask a new question.